# Any good video chat API I could integrate in a ASP .NET MVC 2 web application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, video-streaming

I'm looking for a good video conference API I could use in my ASP .NET MVC 2 web app. I would like something that is easy to use and that is compatible with as many browsers as possible, on Mac and PC. I found TokBox, but it uses flash and it doesn't integrate too well in an aspx view. But something very similar would be great: I want to be able to connect random people easily with sessions and streams, kind of like ChatRoulette.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220672/implementing-webbased-real-time-video-chat-using-html5-websockets/4220882#4220882) should help you. Basically the author suggest to use the draft of HTML Media Capture of Html5.

Also the second answer in the same question ave a nice suggestion imo.